cmd batch script function with return values
I found string functions like toUpper for batch files here, and also on stackoverflow, but I am unable to figure out how to use them. I found several examples and instructions, some of which are contradictory, but none of them worked for me, for some reason. How would I use a function like this in a .bat file? Here is a sample code for toUpper:
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:: Main script starts here
set "arg=exampleString"

:: Output the original
echo Original: %arg%

:: Call the toUpper function to convert %arg% to uppercase
call :toUpper arg

:: Output the result
echo Uppercase: %arg%

EXIT /b 1


:toUpper str -- converts lowercase character to uppercase
if not defined %~1 EXIT /b
for %%a in ("a=A" "b=B" "c=C" "d=D" "e=E" "f=F" "g=G" "h=H" "i=I"
            "j=J" "k=K" "l=L" "m=M" "n=N" "o=O" "p=P" "q=Q" "r=R"
            "s=S" "t=T" "u=U" "v=V" "w=W" "x=X" "y=Y" "z=Z" "ä=Ä"
            "ö=Ö" "ü=Ü") do (
    call set %~1=%%%~1:%%~a%%
)
EXIT /b

What I get is this:
Original: exampleString
Uppercase: "├╝=├£"rg:├╝=├£

What's going on here?
EDIT: added missing return statement (see comments to answer)

nearly...
Add a goto :eof before the subroutine, else the code will run through it unintended.
Second: you already enabled delayed expansion, so use it:
goto :eof
:toUpper str -- converts lowercase character to uppercase
if not defined %~1 EXIT /b
for %%a in ("a=A" "b=B" "c=C" "d=D" "e=E" "f=F" "g=G" "h=H" "i=I"
            "j=J" "k=K" "l=L" "m=M" "n=N" "o=O" "p=P" "q=Q" "r=R"
            "s=S" "t=T" "u=U" "v=V" "w=W" "x=X" "y=Y" "z=Z" "ä=Ä"
            "ö=Ö" "ü=Ü" "ß=SS") do (
    set "%~1=!%~1:%%~a!"
)
EXIT /b 

The output is not quite what you want because of the Umlaute. Add a chcp 65001 at the top of your script to switch to a codepage which can handle them.
I also suggest adding "ß=SS" for proper grammatics.

Thanks! The missing exit /b 1 (or goto :eof) was a mistake I made when inserting the script here. Interestingly, I figured out now that the script works when I cange the name of my variable, i.e., arg to some other random name, idk why this is.

While your solution works I still don't get why this is. And why the script that I got from https://www.dostips.com/ doesn't.

simple (once you know): %%%~1 with %~1 being arg is translated as %%arg, which is interpreted as %%a plus the string rg. Another variable name works because it does NOT start with the letter you use in the for variable (any variable name that starts with that letter won't work).

ooof. work of the devil!
